# Get the database type from EntityFramework's `DbContext`

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The question is really simple: given an instance of an EntityFramework's `DbContext`, I would like to tell between the effective database it is connected do. AFAIK there are current implementations of EF providers for SQL Server, by Microsoft, MySQL, from Oracle, and perhaps for Postgres.

Let's assume I have access "only" to the `DbContext` instance in my method. How do I detect that I am working with MSSQL, MySQL, Postgres, etc.? (I wonder if there is an Oracle client for EF, that would add up)

Currently I can try with some reflection:

- `DbContext.Connection` is normally an instance of `EntityConnection`
- `EntityConnection` exposes `StoreConnection` property, which should be our ADO connection. testing it against known classes (like `MySqlConnection`) should work

However I believe that this approach is a little tricky. A normal App.config contains the following:

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

I am a little confused, I hoped EF had a better API to detect database type in case one needs to perform uncommon operations.

My question is if there is a simpler method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you use this ?

```
DbContext.Database.Connection.GetType().Name
```

If yes, what is the tricky part ?

Comment: That object is always an instance of `EntityConnection`. Tricky means that I don't like using reflection. It is prone to errors. Surely there is no _easy_ "GetDbType()=="MYSQL" API haha

Comment: The `Connection` property does not exist in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.