# Entity Framework: How do you apply provider specific model changes in Entity Framework Core 2.x?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, entity

I have the following code in my DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    // ...

    // Shorten key length for Identity
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.Id).HasMaxLength(127));
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.Id).HasMaxLength(127));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(127);
        entity.Property(m => m.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(127);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(127);
        entity.Property(m => m.RoleId).HasMaxLength(127);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(127);
        entity.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(127);
        entity.Property(m => m.Name).HasMaxLength(127);
    });
```

I only want to apply these changes to the models if the server/provider being used is MySQL. What is the best way to do that?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31344602/454378) answer suggests the following which feels hacky

```
DbContext.Database.Connection.GetType().Name
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46089191/454378) answer suggests using checks such as `Database.IsSqlServer()` which is fine but I cannot find a `Database.IsMySqlServer()` method anywhere

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `Database.IsMySql()`

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you let me know which nuget package or namespace this IsMySql method is defined as I do not see it in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: When installed, every [database provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/) adds its own **extension** methods to some classes. So basically if you can see `UseMySql(…)` on `DbContextOptionsBuilder`, then you should see `IsMySql()` on `DatabaseFacade`. What about MySQL, currently there are 2 providers, I don't know which one you use - I see these methods added by [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)